# How to define an acronym by using other acronym and print the abbreviations together when first used?

Tags: acronyms, acro

I am using `acro` package and like it. However, I have the following problem.

I would like to define for example "dsDNA" using the acronym of "DNA". When I do that, everything is fine as long as I first use "DNA" in the text (section "good" in the working example). However, if I first use "dsDNA" in the text, "DNA" and "dsDNA" are separately displayed in parentheses as shown below (section "bad" in the working example).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[single=true,macros=true,xspace=true]{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{dna}{
short = DNA ,
long = deoxyribonucleic acid
}

\DeclareAcronym{dsdna}{
short = ds\acs{dna} ,
long = double-stranded \ac*{dna}
}

\begin{document}

\section*{good}

\Ac{dna} is a very important molecule. 
The virus xyz contains \dsdna.

Apart from that, \dna exists in almost all cells of the body. In most cases it is \dsdna.

\section*{bad}
\acresetall

The virus xyz contains \dsdna.
\Ac{dna} is a very important molecule. Apart from that, \dna exists in almost all cells of the body. In most cases it is \dsdna.


\end{document}
```

Then it looks like this:

[image]

What I would like to get would be something like this:

```
The virus xyz contains double-stranded deoxyribonucleic acid (dsDNA).
DNA is a very important molecule. 
Apart from that, DNA exists in almost all cells of the body. In most cases it is dsDNA.
```

Is it possible to achieve this somehow?
Using an abbreviation for "double-stranded" doesn't seem feasible to me. In this case I would probably get something like

```
double-stranded (ds) deoxyribonucleic acid (DNA)
```

which is not what I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is exactly the kind of use case I had in mind when I decided to provide

```
\acifused{<id>}{<true>}{<false>}
```

With it you can do the following:

```
\DeclareAcronym{dsdna}{
  short = ds\acs*{dna} ,
  long = double-stranded \acifused{dna}{\acs*{dna}}{\acl*{dna}}
}
```

This means that the short form will be typeset if the acronym `dna` has been used before but the long form if it hasn't. You may notice that I also use the starred form `\acs*` in the short form of `dsdna`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[single=true,macros=true,xspace=true]{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{dna}{
  short = DNA ,
  long = deoxyribonucleic acid
}

\DeclareAcronym{dsdna}{
  short = ds\acs*{dna} ,
  long = double-stranded \acifused{dna}{\acs*{dna}}{\acl*{dna}}
}

\begin{document}

\section*{good}

\Ac{dna} is a very important molecule.  The virus xyz contains \dsdna.  Apart
from that, \dna exists in almost all cells of the body. In most cases it is
\dsdna.

\section*{also good}
\acresetall

The virus xyz contains \dsdna.  \Ac{dna} is a very important molecule.  Apart
from that, \dna exists in almost all cells of the body. In most cases it is
\dsdna.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this seems like what I have been looking for. However, when trying to use `\acifused` the console tells me "Undefined control sequence". I am using TexLive-2013 distribution on Mac OS X 10.8.4. This should be included, right? I saw in the documentation that is a feature that was (recently?) added in v1.3 of the package. I am a latex beginner, I don't know how to check if packages are up to date.

Comment: @MarlinaH `\acifused` has been introduced in v1.3e, the current version on CTAN is `1.4b`. I guess you're using MacTeX? it should include the `tlmgr` for updating the TeX distribution. You should be able to find some posts regarding updates on this site...

Comment: That was it, it works now.